# Design Guidelines - Sizing doesn't add up

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I'm currently wading myself through the [Google Design Guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/) and I'm struggling to implement parts of it in my application.

Following example: [Lists (Multiline) - Avatar with text](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-specs)

Sizes:

> Primary text font: Roboto Regular 16sp
>   Secondary text font: Roboto Regular 14sp
>   Tile height: 72dp
>   Left avatar padding: 16dp
>   Text padding, left: 72dp
>   Text padding, top and bottom: 20dp

So the guidelines say, that a List Item with an avatar and a primary/secondary text should have a top/bottom text-padding of 20dp and the height of the view should be 72dp.
If I implement the stuff above I'll get a XML like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:background="#FFF">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/primary_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingLeft="72dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Primary text"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/primary_text"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="72dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Secondary text with preview of further content"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And that's how it looks like in the Graphical Layout Editor

[image: graphical layout preview]

As you can see the secondary text gets cut off. And it gets even worse when I look at it on a device:

[image: real device]

So my question: Is this yet another "WTF Google" thing or is there something I've misunderstood?

**Note:** *"Just increase the height to X dp and your problem is fixed"* isn't a sufficient answer for me since the Guidelines are so specific about those sizes.

Comment: I feel you dude. The UX guys at my work try to be super fundamentalist about those guidelines. There's two material design guidelines to be found, a general one http://www.google.de/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html and the android one https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html and imho BOTH can't be strictly followed without getting strange results (or we don't follow them correctly, I don't know). 
I try to follow the guidelines where possible but have no problem going astray from them if they don't work out for my screens / views.

Comment: Font-size in sp and a fixed tile height in dp, that can't possibly work.

Comment: @Su-AuHwang I'm considering a fixed height as bad too - but yeah that's what the guidelines say, isn't it? (Btw: Using sp for texts and dp for everything else is totally fine)

Comment: @user3420815 it's fine when the parent view is set to `wrap_content` or is scrollable. It simply can not work properly when the parent view has a fixed height in dp (here the tileheight). To prove my point, go to your device Settings > Accessibility > Vision > Font size and set it to Large or Huge, now check your sample project from above again and see how your layout melts away. (your device settings menu might be slightly different). Guidelines are a good starting point, and it's sad it wasn't completely thought through, but i'd keep the font sizes and just use wrap_content for the height

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have set the height of parent to 72dp.

```
android:layout_height="72dp"
```

set the layout_height attribute to "wrap_content", if you want a fixed height for some reason, you should different layout for different screen.